# Best TensorFlow version & Object Detection API version for Object Detection in Windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, updates, object-detection, tensorflow2.0

Hopefully this questions fits Stack Overflow question type.

So, I have been trying to get TensorFlow 2.0 & 2.1 version up and running for Object Detection, but found myself being constantly stuck with new deprecated/removed functions.

Tensorflow 2.* versions do not fit the model_train.py file which is used to finally train custom object detector, which in case uses old functions -_- from some 1.* versions. It might be a problem on my side, but I've tried both GPU and CPU versions and the original built in object detector did work for me (dogs, kites, and people) for 2.1 version, but no progress for creating custom object detectors due to various incompatibility issues.

Thus, I want to ask if anyone knows best **Tensorflow version** that would work with **some version** of **Object Detection** API from https://github.com/tensorflow/models as of February 2020. CPU/GPU difference does not matter, as I am able to

Thank you!

Comment: I think 1.14 version of TensorFlow works. TensorFlow 2.X is still bringing the support of it.

Answer (score 1):

For trying out tensorflow 2 models use version 2.3.0 , it is compatible with newer models.If using tf 1.x models , use version **1.15.0**.